# asp-action not calling controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have copied the language selector from the [ASP.NET core samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb) and added the SetLanguage method to my

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

However the controller is never called and the is no network request or JavaScript error when I change the language selection. Any suggestions as to what is missing.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    @Localizer["Language:"] <select name="culture" asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The rendered HTML is as follows:

```
<div title="Request culture provider: AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider">
<form id="selectLanguage" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Home/SetLanguage?returnUrl=%2F">
    Language: <select name="culture" id="requestCulture_RequestCulture_UICulture_Name"><option selected="selected" value="en-GB">English (United Kingdom)</option>
<option value="en-US">English (United States)</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="de">Deutsch</option>
<option value="fr">français</option>
</select>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GV_4Y4TrKRMt52xrAg49HFabVGQ6RTHVo2cPjiA2tk3yAtt7EFi-dr3P6wRdR6vj0FqDcXgKwvYef8HrVWa9tFupW9eTJMOBQ848jT_zG2t2-0_XNuAFmnOYfAu3DNBuS6DpF8RF8TfmRdTktOQYzk"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you called `SetLanguage` method using Postman or any other REST API testing tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add the javascript to make the select auto-post?

```
(function () {
$("#selectLanguage select").change(function () {
    $(this).parent().submit();
    });
}());
```

Comment: I didn't add this as I expected ASP.NET to generate code such as this automatically. Adding it didn't help

Comment: What happens when you change the `select` with this code added?  Does it work if you add a submit button?  And no, it won't ever automatically submit a select for you without you telling it to do so.

Comment: do you have jquery in the page, this code depends on jquery. this code comes from the sample code you are trying to mimic https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb/wwwroot/js/site.js

Comment: I wasn't expecting that functionality to be hidden away, it would help if there was a little more in the read-me. I've not been able to get that sample actually running as it refers to nu-get packages that don't appear on nu-get